# How to un-delete SMSes

Tags: sms, data-recovery, mms

A bunch of messages got deleted from my phone. I can see them when using various recovery software (FonePaw etc) but the major flaw of them all is that recovery is only available outside of the phone - saved as external file.

I know there's a way to access the SMS DB via `adb`, like so `adb shell content query --uri content://sms` to list the messages.

I wonder if there's a way to run a similar command to update the database and actually un-delete all deleted messages?

Comment: When it comes to databases on Android most likely it's an SQLite db. If you delete data in an SQLite database then it may be recoverable, however this requires direct access to the database file. If the phone is not rooted you can only get direct access via `adb backup` if the sms app allows backup and your phone isn't running Android 12+.

Comment: FonePaw can restore deleted SMS?